# Open Source JDBC driver for Excel, CSV files on a Maven repo

Tags: excel, maven-2, jdbc, csv, jdbc-odbc

Is there an Open Source Excel/CSV/XML files JDBC driver available on a Maven repository? The JDBC-ODBC bridge mechanism is very cumbersome and does not support DataSource well (Optional feature not implemented exception). Read/write ability is essential, but read-only will do if there's nothing better.

Comment: Why use JDBC? It's pretty heavyweight and cumbersome for writing to files. Go with one of the suggestions below, like OpenCSV, which provides a more appropriate level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

**CsvJdbc** is a Java database driver for reading comma-separated-value files.

http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/

Maven Repo:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.csvjdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>csvjdbc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Usage Example:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DemoDriver
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      // Load the driver.
      Class.forName("org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver");

      // Create a connection. The first command line parameter is
      // the directory containing the .csv files.
      // A single connection is thread-safe for use by several threads.
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:" + args[0]);

      // Create a Statement object to execute the query with.
      // A Statement is not thread-safe.
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

      // Select the ID and NAME columns from sample.csv
      ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID,NAME FROM sample");

      // Dump out the results to a CSV file with the same format
      // using CsvJdbc helper function
      boolean append = true;
      CsvDriver.writeToCsv(results, System.out, append);

      // Clean up
      conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OpenCSV

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Read

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

Write

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
 // feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
 String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
 writer.writeNext(entries);
 writer.close();
```

Comment: While this is an excellent tool, it doesn't really answer the question, specifically when Excel files are involved...